# Процесс входа через СМС в Meteor

Tags: авторизация, аутентификация, meteor

Здравствуйте!

Хочу реализовать вход посредством СМС в приложении Meteor.

Пусть есть простая форма для ввода телефона:

```
<form onSubmit={ this.submitPhone() }>
  <input type='text' size='10' placeholder='Ваш телефон' />
  <input type='submit' value='Отправьте мне код'/>
</form>
```

Пользователь вводит телефон и отправляет форму. Ему приходит СМС с коротким кодом. И появляется следующая форма для кода:

```
<form onSubmit={ this.submitCode() }>
  <input type='text' size='5' placeholder='Ваш код' />
  <input type='submit' value='Войти'/>
</form>
```

Если пользователь ввел код корректно (то есть тот же, что был прислан в смс), то Метеор должен определить его статус как logged in (с определенным _Id, я полагаю).

Нашел забугорный сервис Twilio и вот этот [package](https://github.com/DispatchMe/meteor-accounts-sms). Однако, я даже не представляю, как этим воспользоваться.

Моя работа с системой аккаунтов в Метеоре ограничилась accounts ui в туториале, но там рассматривается скорее размещение формы входа, нежели работа логин-системы. Все что мне нужно - это дать пользователю возможность ввести свой номер телефона, получить смску - и быть залогиненным. В данном случае логин в первый раз - тождественен регистрации.

Буду рад любой помощи, наводкам, возможно подскажете русскоязычный сервис и вариант его использования. По уровню моего вопроса можно точно сказать, что я не разбираюсь в устройстве логина и аккаунтов в метеоре, поэтому надеюсь на детальный ответ, ссылку, статью. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: username будет у вас номером телефона. авторизуйте как обычно loginWithPassword(phone,sms)

Comment: Да, так и реализовал. Пользовался smsaero. Спасибо.